# Can i use DECLARE within a view -sqlserver or CTE?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, view, common-table-expression

I tried various approaches to get the view created with the dynamic variable at the time of creation of the view.

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(64)='ABC'; // <==== attempt

SELECT TOP 10
    U.ID
    ,X.NAME AS yyyy
    ,X.E AS zzzz
FROM TABLE_A U
JOIN TABLE_B X ON U.ID=X.ID
WHERE U.STATUS='HELLO'
**AND X.NAME=@Test**
ORDER BY U.ID DESC
```

I am getting an error even if i try to use CTE

```
CREATE VIEW TESTVIEW AS
WITH Tests AS  (DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(64)='ABC')
    SELECT TOP 10
        U.ID
        ,X.NAME AS yyyy
        ,X.E AS zzzz
    FROM TABLE_A U
    JOIN TABLE_B X ON U.ID=X.ID
    WHERE U.STATUS='HELLO'
    **AND X.NAME=Tests**
    ORDER BY U.ID DESC
```

Comment: You can't declare a variable in a view. You could use a CTE to emulate it, but that seems odd. Why would you not create the view and pass the string you want to filter on in a where clause?

Comment: No, a `VIEW` is effectively a pseudotable defined by a `SELECT`. If you want a parameterised "view" use an inline table value function.

Comment: Your attempt with the CTE makes even less sense. A CTE contains a `SELECT` statement too; you can't `DECLARE` inside one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare a variable in a view. Why would you not create the view and then `SELECT` from the view using the string in the `WHERE` clause?

```
CREATE VIEW TESTVIEW AS
    SELECT TOP 10 -- Wouldn't recommend hardcoding this in a view
        U.ID
        ,X.NAME AS yyyy
        ,X.E AS zzzz
        ,X.NAME 
    FROM TABLE_A U
    JOIN TABLE_B X ON U.ID=X.ID
    WHERE U.STATUS='HELLO';

SELECT
   *
FROM TESTVIEW
WHERE NAME = 'ABC';
```

You could emulate it within the view with a CTE like:

```
CREATE VIEW TESTVIEW AS
    
WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT
       'ABC' as var
)

SELECT TOP 10 --Still wouldn't recommend hardcoding this in a view
        U.ID
        ,X.NAME AS yyyy
        ,X.E AS zzzz
        ,X.NAME 
    FROM TABLE_A U
    JOIN TABLE_B X ON U.ID=X.ID
    WHERE U.STATUS='HELLO'
    AND X.NAME = (SELECT var FROM cte);

SELECT * FROM TESTVIEW;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,it really helps .However i was wondering within a CTE ,if i want to embed multiple values for the test name how can i go about doing that

WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT
       'ABC' as var
)

Comment: since var could be either 'ABC' ,'DEF','XYZ' or anything else also,please suggest

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Do you want the `WHERE` to consider multiple values? As in `X.NAME IN (SELECT var FROM cte)` in the case var has multiple values?

Comment: I really think you're going about this the wrong way. If the variable can be anything, create the view with `X.NAME` in the `SELECT` statement. When you are selecting data from the view, you pass that into the where. `SELECT * FROM TESTVIEW WHERE NAME IN ('abc','def','hij')`

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies and suggestions,that helps as well :)